# Why can't I use "have" in given example?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

How come in following sentence "have" is an incorrect word to use and "has" is correct one?

"Working for many years in academic and administration fields *have* not only contributed to my professional growth but also to..."

"Have" seems to be correct if I take into consideration "academic and administration" but "Has" makes sense if I only concentrate on "Working".

Comment: The subject of the sentence is "Working ...", which is singular.

Comment: _Working for many years in academic and administration fields_ is a clause and clauses as subject take singular verb agreement. (in contrast to NP subjects which can take either singular or plural agreement depending on number.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subject is "working" which is singular; thus "has" is correct.

You're tempted by the "many years" or perhaps by the "academic and administration fields" to make the verb plural, but that just describes the work.

This will be clearer if you boil the sentence down:

> Working ... has not only contributed to my professional growth, but also to...

Comment: Actually the subject is the whole subordinate non-finite clause _Working for many years in academic and administration fields_. Clausal subjects take singular agreement.

Comment: Agreed.  That's why I wrote "Working ..." in my first comment.

Comment: And it's worth noting that *working* is being used a gerund - a verbal noun - here.

Answer (score 1):

The subject is not the first person, so "(implied 'I') has" does not apply. Instead, the subject is "(the experience of) working", and this is handled as third person singular. So the simple version of the sentence is "Working has contributed", rather than "Working have contributed".